# Code to set default browser in html file

Tags: html, browser, default

I've created a file in HTML and would like to set a default browser to have this load from.  Can this be done using HTML, or does javascript have to be added to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that locally as part of a shortcut. So right click in desktop> create new shortcut and you can put the path to the browser followed by the html path.

Try this in the target of the shortcut

```
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" C:\Users\user\Desktop\1.html
```

There will be no other way to start a local program from HTML or JavaScript on the users computer.

Comment: I have done this and the browser is returning an error regarding the file cannot be found.

Comment: Check your path, if the path is correct it will work.

Comment: the path on this is correct, however the shortcut created for this file does not allow others users to access it.  It defaults to a drive letter inconsistent with how they have mapped it.  My guess is there is some form of authentication method used that is preventing access to the file.  I tried using IP, IP with port, name and what appears to be a secondary name and none of them work.  My assumption is that I cannot use a shortcut to target this file based on the way this drive is configured.

Comment: If it is a network mapped drive on all computer, then you should be able to map it to the same drive letter on all computers and then use that in the link. Another option for you could be using a vbscript file. using that you can map the drive first (including credentials) and then open the browser and then file from within the vbs file.

Answer (score 0):

To add to SANM2009's answer: you can't set the default browser via HTML or JavaScript, as this would be a huge security flaw that could be exploited to allow malicious code to be set to run when loading HTML files (with even further potential repercussions).

SANM2009's answer is the most direct way to accomplish what you want to do if you only need to do this on your local computer. If you need to distribute your solution then you could use a batch file or PowerShell file to open a specific browser.

To create a batch file, just open a text editor and enter the following (this will open Firefox in this case):

```
start "firefox.exe" "path to your html file goes here"
```

Save that as a file with a .bat extension, such as openmyhtml.bat, and then you can just double click that file to open your HTML file in Firefox.

To accomplish the same in PowerShell, open a text editor and enter the following:

```
Start-Process "firefox.exe" "path to your html file goes here"
```

Save that with a .ps1 extension, such as openmyhtml.ps1, and then you can double-click that.

Batch files are more universally supported, so that's probably your best bet, unless there's a specific reason you'd want to use PowerShell.

Comment: This is an internal file on a shared drive with 20 other people.  It is in my folder however the shortcut created is in the common folder.  Even in setting this the way that was previously advised, it doesn't open.  See the target here:  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" \\lenel-filesvr\techsupport\ARC\Database_Fundaments.htm   The start in is set to my folder on the shared drive.  When clicking on open file location, it shows me where the chrome.exe file is, which I would understand this to be where it would look for the file I created.

Comment: After further investigating the file, when opening the shortcut it showed the incorrect path to the file in the browser.  I dropped the file in chrome directly to see the path is detected and set that in the target.  It is now working.  Thank you both

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out.

Comment: @AmandaC don't forget to select an answer to your question. :)

Answer (score 0):

After further investigating the file, when opening the shortcut it showed the incorrect path to the file in the browser. I dropped the file in chrome directly to see the path is detected and set that in the target. It is now working. Thank you both